# Selenium IDE If DIV contains Text click on the button

Tags: jquery, html, css, selenium, ide

I try to click on `<button>` element that is child of `<div>`. The `<div>` also contains `<span>` element with certain text that I stored some steps before. I have lots of elements that have the structure below, but only one of them contains the exact text in the `<span>`. Based on the text in this `<span>` I want to click on the `<button>` above.

The structure of the HTML:

```
<td>
  <div>
    <button> Click </button>
    <span> From ORI-1730 </span>
  </div>
</td>
```

I am selecting the span this way:

```
(css=span:contains("${SelectOrder}"))
```

where "SelectOrder" == From ORI-1730.

And tried to select the button with:

```
(css=span:contains("${SelectOrder}").prev())
```

without success.

I have found some themes, but was unable to make them work for me:

[Jquery: Checking to see if div contains text, then action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/902597/jquery-checking-to-see-if-div-contains-text-then-action)

[Select previous element using jQuery selector only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16455449/select-previous-element-using-jquery-selector-only)

Comment: I didn't know how to structure the XPath, but the Andersson's answer helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select required button by using `XPath` instead of `CSS`, like below:

```
xpath=//div[span[contains(text(), "${SelectOrder}")]]/button
```